# How to compare two times in `day.js`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, dayjs

I am trying to compare and find the difference between two times and two dates in `day.js`. My `date` is in `YYYY/MM/DD` format and `time` is in `HH:mm:ss` format.

I am using the following code to compare and find the difference between the two dates

```
const createDate = dayjs(Post.createdOn.date);
const requestDate = dayjs().format("YYYY/MM/DD");
const dateDiff = createDate.diff(requestDate, "day");
console.log(`dateDiff: ${dateDiff}`);
```

Everything is working fine for the `date`.
But when I try to compare the times, I get `NaN` as result. I using the following code to compare and find the difference between the two times:

```
const createTime = dayjs(Post.createdOn.time);
const requestTime = dayjs().format("HH:mm:ss");
const timeDiff = createTime.diff(requestTime, "minute");
console.log(`timeDiff: ${timeDiff}`);
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this one?

```
const timeDiff = createTime.subtract(requestTime, "minute");
```

If it's not working yet, then check the format of `createTime`. I think it's not in the right format.

And also could you please share the error text here? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have double-checked, and the format is correct. I have tried the `subtract`. But now I am getting an error saying `Invalid date`.

Comment: Hi @user597916, I just noticed you are passing only time as requestTime. But it needs the Date too. Otherwise, It can't calculate the difference. You have to pass a date-time string here.
You can checkout their official [doc](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference).

Comment: I am storing date and time as two separate variables. How do I compare these two together?

Comment: Let's keep them together. I mean you don't need to separate them. Just separate them when you are rendering them in the dom. But in DB, save the date-time string together.